# FloatActionButton is not hiding when scrolling

Tags: android, floating-action-button, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm tryng to hide my FAB when scroll down in my Activity but is not working. Why??? Inside the fragment tag has fragments with RecyclerView.

Here's my Activity xml code:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.principal.PrincipalActivity">

<fragment
        android:id="@+id/PrincipalActivity_navHostFragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/principal_nav_graph" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/PrincipalActivity_bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/PrincipalActivity_navHostFragment"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu_principal" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/PrincipalActivity_fabItensPedido"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_carrinho"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:fabSize="auto"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/PrincipalActivity_navHostFragment"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:layout_behavior=".utils.ScrollAnimationFAB" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is the Layout Behavior that i'm using using in the FAB Button, but is not working in the activity, only in the fragments inside the fragment tag.

```
class ScrollAnimationFAB extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<FloatingActionButton> {

    public ScrollAnimationFAB(){
        super();
    }

    public ScrollAnimationFAB(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, @NonNull FloatingActionButton child, @NonNull View directTargetChild, @NonNull View target, int axes, int type) {
        return axes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL ||
                super.onStartNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, directTargetChild, target,
                        axes, ViewCompat.TYPE_TOUCH);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedScroll(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, @NonNull FloatingActionButton child, @NonNull View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed, int type, @NonNull int[] consumed) {

        Log.v("Msg", "dyConsumed: " + dyConsumed + ", dyUnConsumed: " + dyUnconsumed);
        if (dyConsumed > 0 && child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            child.hide(new FloatingActionButton.OnVisibilityChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onHidden(FloatingActionButton fab) {
                    super.onHidden(fab);
                    fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });
        } else if (dyConsumed < 0 && dyUnconsumed == 0 && child.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
            child.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the ploblem this way:

```
recyclerView =
            rootView.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView).apply {
                this.setHasFixedSize(true)
                this.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity?.baseContext)

                this.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                        if (dy > 0)
                            activity_fab.hide()
                        else
                            activity_fab.show()

                    }
                })
            }
```

The FAB view is inside my activity. But this code above is inside the fragment. I call the FAB in my fragment this way: `(activity as AppCompatActivity).findViewById(R.id.activity_fab)`.

Answer (score 0):

Floating action button provides you a method to do that in good way`fab.hide()`

Answer (score 0):

**If the FloatingActionButton is in CoordinatorLayout** - You should use the following code:

```
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams p = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) playlist_FAB_start.getLayoutParams();
    p.setAnchorId(View.NO_ID);
    playlist_FAB_start.setLayoutParams(p);
    playlist_FAB_start.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```